# Setting ADFS Theme for Application Groups via Powershell?

Tags: powershell, adfs, adfs4.0

Currently, we have plenty of WS-FED and SAML applications managed by ADFS 4.0 (ADFS 2016).
For a some of the relying parties (service providers) we've set Custom Web Themes with `Set-AdfsRelyingPartyWebTheme`  as discribed here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsrelyingpartywebtheme?view=windowsserver2016-ps

For example:

```
$RelyingPartyName = "MyRpName"
$WebThemeName = "MyCustomLoginTheme"
Set-AdfsRelyingPartyWebTheme -TargetRelyingPartyName $RelyingPartyName -SourceWebThemeName $WebThemeName
```

This is working without any problem.

We recently started to add OAuth applications (`WebApiApplication` with a `NativeClientApplication`) with ADFS using the `Application Groups` functionality.

The login process is working without any problem.

What I am missing or could not find in the documentation is a powershell command such as

`Set-AdfsNativeClientApplicationWebTheme` or at least `Set-AdfsApplicationGroupWebTheme`

I've also checked alternatives. Neither [Set-AdfsNativeClientApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsnativeclientapplication?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
 nor [Set-AdfsApplicationGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/adfs/set-adfsapplicationgroup?view=windowsserver2022-ps) support a `SourceWebThemeName` parameter.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same exact cmdlet to apply a webtheme to an app inside an application group, just use the application display name (not the identifier) as the -TargetRelyingPartyName parameter. Just be careful that in some cases you have to apply the custom webtheme to the web application or the webapi. It depends on how the authentication is triggered, generally speaking you have to assign the webtheme to the "resource" specified in the authorization request.